# Ввод пароля при открытии приложения

Tags: android, java

Есть ли готовая библиотека, которая будет запрашивать пароль при открытии приложения?

Comment: ШТА? Местный телепат временно не доступен. А что, уже религия запрещает создать свой EditText c inputType="textPassword"?

Comment: @nuclominus я думаю, есть красивые и хорошо шифрующие с некоторыми дополнительными функциями.

Comment: @eldqs трудно md5 от пароля взять? Не придумывайте себе головную боль

Comment: @nuclominus https://github.com/OrangeGangsters/LolliPin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Тынц](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.demo.elegant.login.library)